# JavaFX chart extrapolated value

Tags: java, javafx

I have a line chart with several discrete points and I need Y axis values for possibly undefined X axis values. For example:

Chart has points `(1,2)` and `(3,1)` and I want value for **x = 2** which I expect to be `1.5`. There should be a way to find this value, since its the very value JavaFX is using to draw the graph.

Tried `XAxis#getValueForDisplay` but it just returns `Infinity`.

Is there a more elegant solution to this rather than traversing the X axis and extrapolating the values by hand?

Comment: getValueForDisplay is not what you need. It converts the value from the screen coordinates to your axis coordinates system. What you need probably doesn't exist because the chart data is stored as points, not as a function.

Comment: Yes, i agree with @gearquicker. Something like this does not exist. You have to compute it yourself by mathematical formula. Eventually you can use mosue, and take position from cursor and then use getValueForDisplay for X and Y axis.